# Taking a screenshot with C# WebBrowser doesn't work properly on windows server 2012

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10, windows-server-2012, webpage-screenshot

I've written a function that uses WebBrowser to get a screenshot of a web page in my C# MVC application(this is the reference of the code that I used http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/95439/Get-ASP-NET-C-2-0-Website-Thumbnail-Screenshot).

In more details, on the web page that I'm going to capture there is a youtube iframe and I need the preview of that video is captured on my screenshot.

When I run the function on my computer(OS Windows 8) it works properly, but when I run the function on the published project(on Windows Server 2012) the iframe on the screenshot is not captured(is blank).

I think that probabily the issue is related to something in IE10 on Windows Server, since I use WebBrowser.

I tried to set the configuration of IE on the Server as they are in my computer, and I tried also to install flash player on the server but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have some suggestions?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
**Solution Found:**
I found the solution. According with this topic:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c26bd4c9-d8dc-4d3b-9fdb-a9750508951c/adobe-flash-v113370178-not-properly-working-in-server-2012-rp

I've installed the "Desktop Experience" on Windows Server 2012 and after that now it's working.
Thanks anyway!

Comment: This doesn't sound like something I'd want happening on my Windows Server anyway.

Comment: most likely that iframe has not been downloaded yet, wait until e.Url matches the browser's requested Url

Comment: Is Enhanced Security Configuration enabled on your server's IE? (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815141)

Comment: Also, does the frame where the youtube video load at all, or there's just a black square on its placeholder?

Comment: no, the iframe and the whole page seems to be loaded, I've already tried that solution. I'm pretty sure that is loaded because I've debugged it several times both on my system and on the Server. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've disabled Enhanced Security Configuration

Comment: and on the youtube frame in the screenshot there is a white space(not a black placeholder)